# DotNetOpenAuth Unexpected response Content-Type text/javascript

Tags: oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

Some OAuth providers are not well-behaved, one example being mail.ru.

Their returned content type is text/javascript, motivated by their developers as simplifying their debugging routines.

- We could "improve" the source code of DotNetOpenAuth CTP - but from what I see it is not yet publicly available
- Is there a "well-behaved" way to override the content type interpretation in the current DNOA implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could change the content-type that DNOA sees would be to plug in your own `IDirectWebRequestHandler`, which while allowed, isn't a trivial task and fooling DNOA can often lead to security problems.

The source code to the CTP is available [here](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/oauth2), and in fact the tip of that branch has the change that makes it more lenient in this regard.